# Origin Blocked by cors policy using IGDB API (React.js)

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to use the IGDB API however I am getting the error below

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.igdb.com/v4/artworks' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

In my backend, this is my cors setup

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: "http://localhost:3000" ,
  credentials: true
}))
```

This is my frontend that is making the api call (Frontend is running on port 3000)

```
const gameStartHandler = async () => {
    setIsStartGame(true);
     axios.post("https://api.igdb.com/v4/artworks" , {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Client-ID': key,
        },
        data: "fields alpha_channel,animated,checksum,game,height,image_id,url,width;"
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data)
    })
  };
```

This is a screenshot of my config inside twitch developer console

[image: My twitch dev console config]

I have also tried adding a proxy to my package.json on the backend like so

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3000"
```

But I am still getting that cors error, it is driving me crazy.

Comment: this doesn't sound like something that is being caused by your code. Put another way, you're probably accessing that api from a location (the browser) that it isn't meant to be directly accessed from, or by using headers that force it into a pre-flight required request that the api isn't designed to work with resulting in it not providing a valid preflight.

Comment: You request it from your server instead of teh browser, where CORS isn't a concern.

Comment: @KevinB So basically I should try sending the request from the server ?

Comment: Possibly, if that's how that api is meant to be accessed. That it isn't responding to the preflight when requesting from it with the headers it requires hints to me that either you aren't following the instructions and included more headers than it wants, or it isn't meant to be called from the client. *usually* it's the latter

Comment: It worked when I used the server to send the request rather than the client side

Answer (score 0):

The IGDB API doesn't allow Client Side/browser requests.

As the IGDB API only uses "app access"/Client Credentials tokens, you would be *leaking* what is essentially a password that doesn't belong to the user using your website.

So to access the IGDB API you need a proxy, which can be as simple as your frontend calling your backend and the backend then calling IGDB.

IGDB also has a *low* Rate limit, of 4 concurrent requests. So if you have 5 users trying to use your website, the 5 user might end up with no data as the request has failed.

So make sure to employ caching where possible to reduce requests made to IGDB. Like if two people lookup `Minecraft`, theres no need to do a API round trip for the second user as you recently fetched the API data.

Comment: when I use the backend I get a ton of question marks as my response in my terminal when I console.log the data returned from the API

Comment: Sounds like you didn't GZIP decode or JSON parse the response. So you logged the whole buffer